# Creating list of neighbors from edgelist (Python: accessing tuples with first value specified)

Tags: python, loops, graph, networkx, metis

Using NetworkX, I have acquired a list of tuples describing edges (pairs of vertices) in a graph:

```
G = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 8), (4, 5), (8, 15), (5, 6), (5, 7), (6, 17), (7, 11), (7, 15), (7, 16), (17, 12), (11, 12), (11, 13), (15, 9), (15, 10), (16, 9), (9, 18), (18, 13), (18, 14), (10, 14)]
```

Using this list, I want to loop over each vertex, and find each neighboring vertex, but I want to do this in order. So what I would like to get is for instance a nested list with the `i`th sublist containing each of the neighbors for vertex `i`.

```
Neighbors = [[2, 3, 4], [1, 4], [1, 8], [1, 2, 5], [4, 6, 7], [5, 17], [5, 11, 15, 16], [3, 15], [15, 16, 18], [14, 15], [7, 12, 13], [11, 17], [11, 18], [10, 18], [7, 8, 9, 10], [7, 9], [6, 12], [9, 13, 14]]
```

, but it could also be another sorted data structure.

However, since my graph could potentially contain a million edges and vertices, I want to achieve a routine that will not loop over the whole list for every vertex, since I want to keep the runtime low.

Are there any ways to achieve this? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how many vertices there are without iterating over the whole list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a defaultdict as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(set)

for x, y in G:
    d[x].add(y)
    d[y].add(x)

d
defaultdict(set,
            {1: {2, 3, 4},
             2: {1, 4},
             3: {1, 8},
             4: {1, 2, 5},
             5: {4, 6, 7},
             6: {5, 17},
             7: {5, 11, 15, 16},
             8: {3, 15},
             9: {15, 16, 18},
             10: {14, 15},
             11: {7, 12, 13},
             12: {11, 17},
             13: {11, 18},
             14: {10, 18},
             15: {7, 8, 9, 10},
             16: {7, 9},
             17: {6, 12},
             18: {9, 13, 14}})
```

You can convert the dictionary to a list:

```
[sorted(d[k]) for k in range(1, max(d.keys())+1)]
[[2, 3, 4],
 [1, 4],
 [1, 8],
 [1, 2, 5],
 [4, 6, 7],
 [5, 17],
 [5, 11, 15, 16],
 [3, 15],
 [15, 16, 18],
 [14, 15],
 [7, 12, 13],
 [11, 17],
 [11, 18],
 [10, 18],
 [7, 8, 9, 10],
 [7, 9],
 [6, 12],
 [9, 13, 14]]
```

Comment: This works! Thanks a ton. Could you perhaps explain the difference between a normal dictionary and defauldict?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the original graph `g`, you can iterate through the original edge list (if not, you can construct `g` from `G`):

```
[list(v.keys()) for _,e in g.edge.items()]
#[[2, 3, 4], [1, 4], [8, 1], [1, 2, 5], [4, 6, 7], [17, 5], [16, 11, 5, 15], ...]
```

You can omit `list()` if you are ok with `dict_keys`, which is simply a read-only version of a list:

```
[v.keys() for _,e in g.edge.items()]
#[dict_keys([2, 3, 4]), dict_keys([1, 4]), dict_keys([8, 1]), ...]
```